# is it possible to have an Email Alert to previous user email in an updated email field?

Tags: email, workflow, customer-community

SCENARIO:

Email field has test@test.com. Test@test.com get's an email alert saying "You are now in charge of this" then the manager changes the email field again and puts johndoe@yahoo.com.  Is it possible for test@test.com to get an email alert saying "the record is *not assigned to you anymore* and johndoe@yahoo.com was assigned to it."

is it possible?

Comment: you may want to use trigger for notification

Answer (score 1):

You may use apex trigger to stamp previous changed email on to another email field ,call it previous email.

In your workflow email alert you can use previous email field .

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a workflow field update using the priorvalue function.

Whenever the email is changed, you can store the prior value of the email to a custom field, and use that field as the recipient in the email alert.

Field updates always process before email alerts, so you will be fine.